# Terraform private GKE Cluster with Cloud NAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Sorry if this has been asked before. I am trying to find an example of how to terraform a private GKE Autopilot Cluster with Cloud NAT.

In short, I am looking to build a new autopilot GKE cluster with one public IP Address

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A **Github issue** has already been raised and fixed for the support of **GKE Autopilot in Terraform** and you can review the details [here](https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/pull/1148).

I would also recommend checking the [GKE Autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#comparison) and [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/set-up-manage-network-address-translation#creating_nat) documentation.

And here are some additional references for Terraform equivalents for both functions:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#nested_private_cluster_config
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/cloud-nat/google/latest